# Prove that $\nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec A) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec A) - \nabla^2\vec A$. For any vector function of $\vec A$.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields, cross-product, laplacian

Show that $\nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec A) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec A) - \nabla^2\vec A$. For any vector function of $\vec A$.

Comment: Doesn't this just come from the definition of the vector Laplacian? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Vector_Laplacian

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The question has been previously asked, and a detailed answer is available there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381381/showing-that-nabla-times-nabla-times-veca-nabla-nabla-cdot-veca-de?rq=1